# Software for navigating a network diagram

Tags: software-rec, graph

I would like to visualize a large amount of data as a network diagram, such as the one seen [in this graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWorldWideWebAroundWikipedia.png) (but much more complex).

Is there any software available that can import a huge database and allow one to navigate to different parts of the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphViz should be able to produce output very similar to your link.

See: http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation.php

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to use Gephi. https://gephi.org/users/download/

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what kind of database you have.

If you have your data in Text Outline format, MS Word or MS Excel, then you can import it to MindMap.

Read more here: [conceptdraw.com/solution-park/collaboration-mind-map-exchange](http://www.conceptdraw.com/solution-park/collaboration-mind-map-exchange#!story) and here: [conceptdraw.com/helpdesk/how-to-import-excel-file-to-mind-map](http://www.conceptdraw.com/helpdesk/how-to-import-excel-file-to-mind-map)